# How to change image using jquery before prompt existing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

I have three images and need to load according to the Country/Region. One is default and other two images are changing. I am getting the Country from the user IP and using jQuery I am changing the image. **Image changing clearly visible and I want to ignore that**. Can I do that ? I tried making a delay but it is loading in the same way.

Here is my code so far.

```
if(country == "xx") {
    jQuery("#img").attr("src", "image_url");
    setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#imgoverlay').css("opacity", "0.9"); }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#imgbox').css("opacity", "1"); }, 2000);

} else if(country == "yy") {
    jQuery("#img").attr("src", "image_url");
    setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#imgoverlay').css("opacity", "0.9"); }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#imgbox').css("opacity", "1"); }, 2000);
}
```

I have already added the `visibility: hidden` in CSS. When running this `if else` I am facing the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: provide a running demo please!

Comment: add your code inside $(document).ready(function(){ // jquery code })

Comment: @Affan It is already in the `$(document).ready`